# How to create multiple sub domains pointing to same Kubernetes service using ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, saas

We have a Saas application for which we can create multiple subscriptions. Whenever a new subscription is created, we need to create a new alias route with the subscription name to the same application.

**Example:**

application domain: *bookstore.oraganization.com*

subscription name: *silver-plan*

Now a new alias route needs to be created with "*silver-plan-bookstore.oraganization.com*"

**Current Approach:**
We are creating an ingress resource for each application as mentioned in below yaml file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: bookstore
  annotations:
    ...

spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - bookstore.oraganization.com
      secretName: 
  rules:
   - host: bookstore.oraganization.com
     http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: bookstore-service
          servicePort: 8080
   - host: silver-plan-bookstore.oraganization.com  <--- this alias route is created using java client library at runtime when subscription is created
     http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: bookstore-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

We are using a Kubernetes java client to create the alias route at runtime whenever a new subscription is created for the application.

**Problem:**
With our current approach whenever we upgrade the application helm chart which contains the ingress resource definition, all the alias routes created using the java client library are getting DELETED or DROPPED.

I need your help to understand whether my current approach is correct or what is better or another way to achieve this requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

##### A record

```
*.organization.com
```

##### ingress.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: bookstore
  annotations:
    ...

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "*.organization.com"
    secretName: <secret>
  rules:
   - host: "*.organization.com"
     http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: bookstore-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: Hi @RaiBnod,  I should be able to create new routes dynamically at runtime. I need to add a new route whenever a new subscription for an application is added to our system.

Comment: Updated the answer, Ingress supports wildcard for such cases.

Comment: Interesting! I will explore whether this solution fits my requirement. Thanks :)